# When does Fairy Tail 2014 episode 66 to present get English dubbed?

Tags: fairy-tail

I would like to know when episode 66 and onward of Fairy Tail 2014 gets English dubbed.

Comment: Closer voters: Memor-X's answer demonstrates that the event has in fact been announced, so this question should not be closed as being about unannounced future events. If you don't like it, downvote, but don't vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fairy_Tail_episodes#English) Funimation will release Fairy Tail ***episode 241***<sup>1</sup> on September 6, 2016 as apart of Part 21 of the Home Media Release (Episode 240 - 252)

this is also confirmed on the [Funimation Store](http://shop.funimation.com/Fairy-Tail-Part-Twenty-One)

> Fairy Tail - Part Twenty One 
>   Blu-ray & DVD
>   Rating: TV-14
>   **ReleaseDate: 9/6/2016**

Note that Funimation uses the weird US style of dates where it's MM/DD/YYYY and not DD/MM/YYYY so the date in the quote is indeed September 6th and not June 9th.

---

<sup>1: Fairy Tail 2014 series is Season 7 and Fairy Tail Zero according to Wikipedia and still retains the episode order. as such Fairy Tail 2014 episode 66 = 175 (last episode of Season 6) + 66 = 241</sup>